# Apply format to part of a cell based on contents of another cell

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm trying to apply a specific format to a portion of a cell, based on the contents of another cell.

I'm a VBA beginner, and have been able to apply different formats to certain parts of a cell, based on position in a string, but can't get further than that.

Sheet 1, column F has strings of SKU's (separated by commas). I want to make Individual SKU's bold once a check has been performed on that product.
I'm importing data to sheet 2, where column D contains SKU's of products that have been checked.

So to summarise,  I want individual SKU's within a string in column F on sheet 1 to be bold , based on the presence of that SKU in column D on sheet 2

Can anyone assist with the VBA code necessary? I would be most grateful for any assistance.

(I have searched many forums and haven't found the answer so far)

Edit:
I've found the following, and can work with it. It's based on set variables though,not dynamic:

```
Sub test()

    For row_num = 1 To 13

        'Cell contents
        cell_text = Cells(row_num, 1)

        'Same contents split into three parts and saved in an array
        text_array = Split(cell_text, " ")

        'Length of part 1
        length_1 = Len(text_array(0))

        'Length of part 2
        length_2 = Len(text_array(1))

        'Set ITALICS for Part 1
        Cells(row_num, 1).Characters(1, length_1).Font.Color = vbGreen

        'Set BOLD for Part 2
        Cells(row_num, 1).Characters(length_1 + 2, length_2).Font.Bold = 
        True

    Next

End Sub
```

It's still a hypothetical issue, but a very small example of the contents of the two columns is in the following file

[Example data](http://www.filedropper.com/partialcellformatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so if understood correctly and based on your text *"So to summarise, I want individual SKU's within a string in column F on sheet 1 to be bold , based on the presence of that SKU in column D on sheet 2"* you want to:

- Loop through the rows in column D on Sheets(2).
- Find any match in column F on Sheets(1).
- Highlight (Bold text) that number in the string.

I'll try get you in the right direction:

**1).** First things first, you want to loop through all rows in column D on Sheets(2) dynamically. Many ways to do this but personally I like to use `.UsedRange`. For example:

```
Dim CL As Range
For Each CL In Sheets(2).UsedRange.Columns(4).Rows
    'Your code Part 2
Next CL
```

**2).** Now you have to find a match of these values within column F on Sheets(1). A smart/quick way to do so is to make use of `.FindNext` looking at value parts. In action this would look like something like this:

```
Dim CLL as Range
Dim FirstAddress as String
With Sheets(1).Columns(6)
    Set CLL = .Find(What:=CL.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not CLL Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = CLL.Address
        Do
            'You code Part 3
            Set CLL = .FindNext(CLL)
        Loop While Not CLL Is Nothing And CLL.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
```

**3).** Now we are finding the appropriate cells that contain the values we are looking for we need to determine the position of our value in the whole string. We can use something handy for this called `.InStr`. What this function does is determine the position of the first character of our value within the whole string. In practice it would look like this:

```
Dim POS as Long
POS = InStr(1, CLL.Value, CL.Value)
```

The "1" indicates from what position in the string we want to start our search. CLL.Value is whole string we looking in, making CL.Value our searchvalue.

**4).** Now we are able to indicate where our string starts AND we want to know the length of our searchvalue which we can use the `.Len` function for resulting in a numeric value.

```
=Len(CL.Value)
```

**5).** Almost there right? Just need to make the characters bold using `.Characters`. There is a `Bold` setting we can set to `True`. It's quite nice and is used like so:

```
CLL.Characters(POS, Len(CL.Value)).Font.Bold = True
```

`POS` here functions as our starting location while `LEn(CL.Value)` obviously is the length of what we need in bold.

**6).** Here we are. If we would piece all of this together:

```
Sub CreateBold()

Dim CL As Range, CLL As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim POS As Long

For Each CL In Sheets(2).UsedRange.Columns(4).Rows
    With Sheets(1).Columns(6)
        Set CLL = .Find(What:=CL.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not CLL Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = CLL.Address
            Do
                POS = InStr(1, CLL.Value, CL.Value)
                CLL.Characters(POS, Len(CL.Value)).Font.Bold = True
                Set CLL = .FindNext(CLL)
            Loop While Not CLL Is Nothing And CLL.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
Next CL

End Sub
```

Hopefully this DOES answer your question and has been clear enough to understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It does answer my question, and the way you took me through step by step was incredibly helpful! Thank you again!